# how to get the words after the slash in SQL query

Tags: sql-server

I have a date which look like this "Corporate Services\Corporate Affairs & Communications(DP19)"

I want to the result to be like this:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Corporate Service | Corporate Affairs & Communications (DP19) |

I already tried using substring but no luck,
I am using Microsoft SQL

Comment: Not sure on the exact answer but I'd create a SQL function that returns the value either to the left or right of the separator. That function does the complicated work, then it will be simple for use in a query.

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns

Comment: You can probably do with SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX in a custom function.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @AData VARCHAR(1000) = 'Corporate Services\Corporate Affairs & Communications(DP19)';

SELECT
    LEFT(@AData, CHARINDEX('\', @AData) - 1) AS [Column A],
    SUBSTRING(@AData, CHARINDEX('\', @AData) + 1, LEN(@AData)) AS [Column B];
```

I kind of cheated with using `LEN(@AData)` for the `Length` parameter of the `SUBSTRING()` function used in `Column B`, but [`SUBSTRING()` doesn't care](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), so no harm no foul:

> length
>
> ...If the sum of start and length is greater than the number of characters in expression, the whole value expression beginning at start is returned.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `PARSENAME`

```
declare @t table(ch varchar(max))
insert into @t values
(N'Corporate Services\Corporate Affairs & Communications(DP19)');

SELECT 
PARSENAME(REPLACE(ch,'\','.'),2) AS N'Column A' ,
PARSENAME(REPLACE(ch,'\','.'),1) AS N'Column B'
FROM @t
```

Comment: Note this may have unexpected results when any other text passed in contains a period in it, that's meant to be part of the text. E.g. `www.CorporateServices.com\Corporate Affairs & Communications(DP19)`. Of course, OP provided very little context, so who knows if it matters to them. Interesting use of `PARSENAME()` nonetheless.